# Can QInputDialog display TeX?

Tags: python, math, tex

I would like to try and write a small app that asks the user to input the solution to a displayed equation. I know how to get the basic user input through `QInputDialog`. Is there is a way to do this so as to have the equations displayed in `TeX` style maths?

Comment: Would generating an image from the TeX source work? Similar to what [mimetex](http://www.forkosh.com/mimetex.html) does? You can then simply show the image with the formula in the dialog